# Android Dev: Current Time range check

Tags: android

I'm working on an android application, as part of me trying to learn android programming, that will switch audio profiles based on day and time (provided by the user)... So far I have got most of the layout done, I have also created a service that will run in the background to perform few checks...

Right now I'm having a hard time trying to find an elegant way to handle checking if current time falls in time range saved by the user... I'm saving the user's preference for time range in a string format from androids TimerPicker control, I need to check if the current time falls in the user saved times...

Right now I have the following code:

the 'from time' is coming in with the following: hour:minute:AM/PM -- 8:59:AM in string format

the 'to time' is coming in with the following: hour:minute:AM/PM -- 4:59:PM in string format

```
if(fromAMPM.equals("AM")){
        from.set(from.AM_PM, from.AM);
} else {
        from.set(from.AM_PM, from.PM);
}

//dont care about the YEAR and MONTH, so set it to current MONTH and YEAR                                      
from.set(rightNow.get(rightNow.YEAR), rightNow.get(rightNow.MONTH), dayOfWeek, fromHour, fromMinute);                  

if(toAMPM.equals("AM")){
        to.set(to.AM_PM, to.AM);
}else{
        to.set(to.AM_PM, to.PM);
}      

//dont care about the YEAR and MONTH, so set it to current MONTH and YEAR                      
to.set(rightNow.get(rightNow.YEAR), rightNow.get(rightNow.MONTH), dayOfWeek, toHour, toMinute);

//this is just for me to see what got set:
SimpleDateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm aaa");  
String formattedDate1 = df3.format(from.getTime());
String formattedDate2 = df3.format(to.getTime());
```

After all this processing:

```
formattedDate1 is returning: 08:59 AM

formattedDate2 is returning: 04:59 AM
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Calendar documentation, under the section "Inconsistent Information"

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

You call:

`to.set(rightNow.get(rightNow.YEAR), rightNow.get(rightNow.MONTH), dayOfWeek, toHour, toMinute);`

Which sends toHour as HOUR_OF_DAY (24h), not HOUR (12h).

It says that when you supply it with inconsistent information, it just uses the latest information. You're telling it that toHour is 4 on a 24hour scale, which is inconsistent with your PM setting, so it throws the PM setting away.

The easiest change would probably be just to add 12 to toHour instead of setting the AM_PM. Or, don't use the set(year, month, day, hourofday, minute) command and just set hour and am_pm separately.

Comment: thanks for your input, i did not realize that it was the 24h that it was passing into the set...i must have read that Calendar page several times now...in anycase, i just removed the to.set and set the hour and time separately, and that got it working...thanks again...